# how to pick second element starting from the last one?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

[image]

I have two elements and they have the same class and I want to pick  the second element starting from the last one.
( I hope image tells you everything)

I tried `nth-child` but my two elements have same class which is why I can't do with `nth-child` any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `nth-last-child(2)` or `nth-last-of-type(2)`, this will select the 2nd last item.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block
}
li:nth-last-child(2) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```